# Make call to http://localhost:xxxx from https website

Tags: content-security-policy

I understand the CSP that won't allow mixed content on Firefox and Safari, though Chrome allows it.

Is there any way to whitelist an HTTP call to `http://localhost:1234` from an online website accessed via HTTPS (without modifying browser config)?

Comment: do you think there should be a workaround for breaking security? So how do you protect yourself for attacks?

Comment: If Chrome + Opera don't implement it by default, I think it's discussable. Websites could enforce this CSP themselves by adding the `block-mixed-content` meta tag.